# Detect user's running rate

Tags: ios, core-motion

I would like to implement fitness app for learning purpose. I would like to detect the user's action such as running,walking. According to my research, now I am able to detect the user's activity using motionActivityManager from CoreMotion framework. Now I would like to detect the user's rate. For example, user is running in what kilomiles per hour.

Can anyone give any suggestions to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check out the documentation on core motion here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocation

You can get the devices speed and heading using the speed and course variables. The speed variable is in meters per second, so you can easily convert to km/s from there

Comment: When I research on CLLocation as u suggested, I dun really need to use CoreMotion to calculate user's pace. It helps me a lot. Thanks.